# XML Argument Exception

Tags: c#, xml, metadata, .net

I am writing a program that gets metadata information from an mp3 and then stores it into a xml file. I get an error when trying to write the file. The error is: `Argument Exception Invalid name character in 'Nirvana`

```
OpenFileDialog getFiles = new OpenFileDialog();
getFiles.Multiselect = true;
 if (getFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
   foreach (String mp3Files in getFiles.FileNames)
    {
     byte[] Buffer = new byte[128];
     FileStream mediaFile = new FileStream(mp3Files, FileMode.Open);
     mediaFile.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
     mediaFile.Read(Buffer, 0, 128);
     string isMP3 = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 0, 3);
       if (isMP3.CompareTo("TAG") == 0)
        {
          string Album = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 63, 30);
          string Artist = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 33, 30);
          XMLFileToFile.WriteElementString(Artist, Album); //Error here.
          XMLFileToFile.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it is telling you that the single quote ' in 'Nirvana is invalid and must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

These are the escape characters in a XML file that you should avoid:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

You can use this chart while you are converting your escape characters:

<kbd>**Original Character**</kbd><kbd>**XML entity replacement**</kbd><kbd>**XML numeric replacement**</kbd>
<kbd><</kbd>                              <kbd>&lt;</kbd>                                    <kbd>&#60;</kbd>                                    
<kbd>></kbd>                              <kbd>&gt;</kbd>                                   <kbd>&#62;</kbd>                                    
<kbd>"</kbd>                               <kbd>&quot;</kbd>                               <kbd>&#34;</kbd>                                    
<kbd>&</kbd>                              <kbd>&amp;</kbd>                               <kbd>&#38;</kbd>                                    
<kbd>'</kbd>                               <kbd>&apos;</kbd>                               <kbd>&#39;</kbd>

For your code you can write something like:

```
string Album = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 63, 30).ValidateXML();
string Artist = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 33, 30).ValidateXML();
XMLFileToFile.WriteElementString(Artist, Album); //This should run smoothly.

static string ValidateXML(this string value)
{
   return value.Replace(@"""","&quot;").Replace("'","&apos;").Replace("<","&lt;").Replace(">","&gt;").Replace("&","&amp;");
}
```

Comment: Windows forms does not like static. :(

Comment: @user3679968, you can create a class that has the main namespace of your application then you can call it from there or just change this method and make a void and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your string, the single quote is throwing your code out of whack.

Try something like this.

```
Filename = Filename.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

With `WriteElementString` you are trying to use `Artist` as the name of your node, and for the error you report, it contains a quote, which is not a valid character for a node name. Try removing quotes and other invalid characters.